# Intellij is blocking my print-screen keypresses

Tags: intellij-idea, greenshot

I have noticed that whenever I have an Intellij window in focus, and press the print-screen key, the keypress does not make it through to Green-shot, which I use for screenshots. If I but any other window in focus, Greenshot activates as expected.
Does anyone know how to persuade Intellij to get off my back and let me take screenshots in peace? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, this happens when the other program (in this case, IntelliJ) is running with administrator privileges while Greenshot isn't.

The behavior is by design in Windows' User Account Control.

You can e.g. start Greenshot with admin privileges, too. Or try starting IntelliJ without. Both solutions should fix the problem.

For more informations, see the [Greenshot FAQ entry: Why does the Print key not work in some windows?](https://getgreenshot.org/faq/why-does-the-print-key-not-work-in-some-windows/) or my [answer to another question](https://superuser.com/a/1296065).

---

*Disclosure: I am member of the Greenshot team.*

Comment: I guess Greenshot will start as admin then, as I have to start Intellij as admin because of group policies on Windows.